# Two different MYSQl instances on same machine?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5

I have MySQL 5.6 installed (Linux).

```
/var/lib/mysql
/etc/my.cnf
```

I have a cold backup that I am recovering:

```
/var/lib/mysql_backup
/etc/mybackup.cnf
```

In April I was able to get the backup started and it had been running fine until I had to reboot my machine 2 days ago to release an unmount that wouldn't succeed.

Now, I attempt to restart that second instance and I get an error that doesn't make sense given that it was working for nearly 6 months nonstop before and simultaneous/in parallel with the other instance.

```
root@VENUS:/var/lib/mysql_backup# mysqld --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/mybackup.cnf --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld_backup.pid
2013-10-19 15:48:07 22026 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
mysqld: Can't find file: 'plugin' (errno: 2 - No such file or directory)
2013-10-19 15:48:07 22026 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
2013-10-19 15:48:07 22026 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2013-10-19 15:48:07 22026 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2013-10-19 15:48:07 22026 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2013-10-19 15:48:07 22026 [Note] InnoDB: CPU does not support crc32 instructions
2013-10-19 15:48:07 22026 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2013-10-19 15:48:07 22026 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2013-10-19 15:48:07 22026 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2013-10-19 15:48:07 22026 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2013-10-19 15:48:07 22026 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2013-10-19 15:48:07 22026 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2013-10-19 15:48:07 22026 [Note] InnoDB: 1.2.10 started; log sequence number 1642375387
2013-10-19 15:48:07 22026 [Note] Recovering after a crash using /var/log/mysql_backup/mysql-bin
2013-10-19 15:48:07 22026 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
2013-10-19 15:48:07 22026 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
2013-10-19 15:48:07 22026 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '192.168.1.70'; port: 3310
2013-10-19 15:48:07 22026 [Note]   - '192.168.1.70' resolves to '192.168.1.70';
2013-10-19 15:48:07 22026 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '192.168.1.70'.
2013-10-19 15:48:07 22026 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Can't find file: 'user' (errno: 2 - No such file or directory)
```

What am I missing here? Nothing has change from the first time it was running.

Comment: If the 'datadir' is /var/lib/mysqld_backup then inside that directory, there should be a directory for each schema, including one called "mysql."  Inside mysql should be plugin.frm plugin.myd user.frm user.myd and others, for several system and grant tables.  The error is complaining that they aren't there, in /var/lib/mysqld_backup/mysql.  What do you see there?

Comment: Slight mistake. My --defaults-file option should have been --defaults_file.
But now the error is:
131019 15:09:25 mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists

Comment: Rephrasing the question based on the stupid error calling the option.

Comment: dang. I double checked. I had the option right the first time.

Comment: The option is [--defaults-file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/option-file-options.html) ... where are you on the issue at this point? Process already exists or no such file or directory? You definitely can run multiple instances on a single machine.  I think my record is around 8. :)

Comment: Please [consider deleting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068) your [cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19470478).

Comment: So, no tips then?

Comment: Where do you stand at this point?  "process already exists" or "no such file or directory?"  Could be /etc/mysql/mybackup.cnf isn't the correct .cnf.  It needs to reference the port that you want MySQL to run on vs. the standard "3306".

Comment: Okay, so what's inside the directory /var/lib/mysqld_backup/mysql?  You didn't have a partition that didn't get mounted on reboot, did you?

Comment: There are a bunch of things in that directory, including user.frm, user.myd and user.myi

No partition is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Since I am doing partial recovery on a damaged database (I did an iso image cold backup, but did not give the iso maker the proper options and ended up with DOS 8.1 filenames, when they should have been Joliet Long names) I must have previously used the option --skip-grant .

i used the command 
    mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/mybackup.cnf --skip-grant
and the database started up fine.

Now to continue recovering what I can.

Comment: oh, lol ... [I remember you](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40536/).